# Keyboard size is bigger

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, keyboard

I wanna show keyboard smaller but causing problem 
compare both images , keyboard size is bigger than first image and also vertical spacing between two character is more 
when i add ratina 4.7 splash screen keyboard showing smaller but my app design causing problem and when i remove 4.7 splash screen working fine but keyboard showing bigger
How i can show keyboard smaller without design problem
I searched lot but never get solution of this problem

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same Issue with my App When complete my app I see the keyboard is bigger compared to other apps.

I Found many solutions but not working then I just found that **"When you don't add the 4.7" splash screen the UI is automatically scaled up by the OS to fit the bigger screens. That's why the keyboard is bigger."**

Now see the Following Screenshot.

**Before Without add 4.7 inch splash screen** 
[image]

**After adding a 4.7-inch splash screen .**

[image]

Happy Coding <3

Answer (score 3):

When you don't add the 4.7" splash screen the UI is automatically scaled up by the OS to fit the bigger screens. Thats why the keyboard is bigger.

To fix this issue you need to formally support iPhone 6 devices by adding the splash screens. And manually manage the UI. Using auto layout & size classes you can easily support bigger views.

Comment: But i m using autoresizing for manage UI, and what is the solution for show small keyboard

Comment: I think it is time to adopt auto layout & size classes. And support bigger screens. Otherwise you can't control the scaling

Comment: If you think that my question will help others then please vote up

Answer (score 0):

If you add the splash screen of 6 and 6+ then IOS will use the same size of all your UI.

and if not IOS will stretch all your UI will result in increase height.

Comment: Show what should i do for small keyboard

Comment: Make your app compatible with 6 and 6+ using autolayout no another option. or let it go as it is

Comment: If i use autolayout for manage UI than keyboard will show smaller or bigger ?

Comment: It will take the default height smaller than the scalled UI

Comment: If you think that my question will help others then please vote up

Comment: Independent of whether or not I have autolayout turned on, my app uses a small keyboard. I don't have any launch images configured and am using my Main.storyboard as my Launch Screen File.