# Old iOS app View controllers not resizing properly on bigger devices

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, autoresizingmask

I'm having problem with `autolayout`, at least I think that's the problem.

[image: This is screenshot from iPhone 6S and as you can see it's not resizing like it should with AutoLayout. Everything is bigger than it should be on that device.]

I tried with `AutoResizing`, but no good. Did anyone experienced this?

[image]

It's like when running the app that was made for iPhone 5 on iPhone 6, like older iOS apps.

Comment: are you facing issue with only search bar or all other view of viewController?

Comment: For all views in all viewControllers. It looks like its not scaling at all. Same thing is for Payoneer iOS app, if you have time you can check it out and see. Same thing.

Comment: its due to the some what mistake you made with your constraints buddy

Comment: the search bar constraints suggest you miss the Top one so its display some space between navigationBar and SearchBar

Comment: No no, everything is positioned where it should be, that's not the issue. Take a look at the keyboard for example, it shouldn't be that big on iPhone 6S, don't you think? Also the font size in navigation bar. That's my issue, why is keyboard that big?

Comment: But man keyboard size is fix I don't think we can resize it

Comment: Download Payoneer app, start it and check the sizes. After that start any other app that updated regularly and spot the difference.

Comment: You need to add a launch screen storyboard or launch images for the larger devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is in AppIcons and Launch Images, referring to https://stackoverflow.com/a/30843765/4551952

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's look like bad constraints of the views and subviews.
If you are taking about your search bar then what it looks like missing Top constraints. due to missing of top constraints your search bar not comping to the top position of the view or below navigation bar

image describe more about it

[image]

Comment: It's not related to the search bar, it is positioned where it should be, keyboard, navigation bar font size, everything is much bigger than it should be on the iPhone 6 device